# Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component when launching my Sitecore Commerce site

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I have recently encountered the question related to Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (1709) breaking Sitecore Commerce 8.2.1 Update 2 installs. I had a perfectly working Sitecore Commerce 8.2.1 Update 2 site. When I installed the Windows 10 Fall Creators Update, I started getting the error below. When I rolled back the Windows 10 Fall Creators Update, the site started working again. Has anyone found a cause or fix for this issue - other than rolling back the Windows 10 Update?

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Error
>   HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [COMException (0x80004005): Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned
>   from a call to a COM component.]
>   CommerceServer.Core.Interop.Profiles.ProfileServiceClass.Initialize(String
>   sConfigStore, String sCatalog) +0
>   CommerceServer.Core.Runtime.Profiles.ProfileContext..ctor(String
>   profileServiceConnectionString, String providerConnectionString,
>   String bdaoConnectionString, DebugContext debugContext) +808
>
> [CommerceProfileSystemException: Failed to initialize profile service
>   handle.]
>   CommerceServer.Core.Runtime.Profiles.ProfileContext..ctor(String
>   profileServiceConnectionString, String providerConnectionString,
>   String bdaoConnectionString, DebugContext debugContext) +1385
>   CommerceServer.Core.Runtime.CommerceContextFactory.CreateProfileContext()
>   +939    CommerceServer.Core.Runtime.CommerceContextFactory.get_ProfileContextSingleton()
>   +116    CommerceServer.Core.Runtime.Profiles.CommerceProfileModule.get_ModuleProfileContext()
>   +129    CommerceServer.Core.Runtime.Profiles.CommerceProfileModule.get_ProfileContext()
>   +178    Sitecore.Commerce.Connect.CommerceServer.Pipelines.CommerceProfileProcessor.Begin(CommerceProfileModule
>   module) +25
>   Sitecore.Commerce.Connect.CommerceServer.Pipelines.CommerceBaseModuleProcessor`1.BeginRequest(PipelineArgs
>   args) +92
>
>   Sitecore.Commerce.Connect.CommerceServer.Pipelines.CommerceBaseModuleProcessor`1.Init(PipelineArgs
>   args) +176    (Object , Object[] ) +74
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +469
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
>   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Application_Start() +288
>   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app) +670
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +581
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +418
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +369
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Failed to initialize profile service
>   handle.]    System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext
>   context) +534
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +111    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +718

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A hot fix for this issue was released:

Download [hotfix](https://dl.sitecore.net/hotfix/Commerce/SC%20Hotfix%2034492-1%20Commerce.CSCore%2011.4.152.zip) :  unzip the file and follow above instructions:

1. Backup the original binary "dsdb3.dll" located under the default install location c:\Program Files\Commerce Server 11\UPM\
2. Replace the dsdb3.dll from above location with the one found from this hotfix package
3. Restart IIS

The hotfix was built for Sitecore Commerce 8.2.1(Update-2) with Commerce Server 11.4.148, and you should not install it on other Sitecore versions

Details about this issues was published on KB site: https://kb.sitecore.net/en/Articles/2017/12/18/21/17/006092.aspx

Comment: After replacing the dsdb3.dll my sitecore comerce server error is fixed but now it's not showing launchpad. It is showing not found exception for launchpad.